# Nested list comprehensions in Julia

Tags: julia

In python I can do nested list comprehensions, for instance I can flatten the following array thus:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[i for arr in a for i in arr]
```

to get `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

If I try this syntax in Julia I get:

```
julia> a
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])

julia> [i for arr in a for i in arr]
ERROR: syntax: expected ]
```

Are nested list comprehensions in Julia possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

List comprehensions work a bit differently in Julia:

```
> [(x,y) for x=1:2, y=3:4]
2x2 Array{(Int64,Int64),2}:
 (1,3)  (1,4)
 (2,3)  (2,4)
```

If `a=[[1 2],[3 4],[5 6]]` was a multidimensional array, `vec` would flatten it:

```
> vec(a)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Since a contains tuples, this is a bit more complicated in Julia. This works, but likely isn't the best way to handle it:

```
function flatten(x, y)
    state = start(x)
    if state==false
        push!(y, x)
    else
        while !done(x, state) 
          (item, state) = next(x, state) 
          flatten(item, y)
        end 
    end
    y
end
flatten(x)=flatten(x,Array(Any, 0))
```

Then, we can run:

```
> flatten([(1,2),(3,4)])
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: So is there no way to flatten the array using a list comprehension as you can in Python?

Comment: I'm quite confused by your `a=[[1,2],[[3,4],[5,6]]]` statement since `[[1,2],[[3,4],[5,6]]] == [1,2,3,4,5,6]` returns `true`

Comment: To my knowledge, Julia doesn't have the concept of nested list comprehensions. Instead, it has multivariate comprehensions where each variable corresponds to a dimension of the output array. Given that, you can't flatten a list comprehension in Julia. (Also made a correction to the answer - copied the wrong array over)

Comment: @BenHamner Would you mind correcting the "right answer" for this question? The feature that you asked for has been added to the language. Jeff's answer shows how you can use it.

Answer (score 27):

This feature has been added in julia v0.5:

```
julia> a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])

julia> [i for arr in a for i in arr]
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get some mileage out of using the [splat operator](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#varargs-functions) with the array constructor here (transposing to save space)

```
julia> a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])

julia> [a...]'
1x9 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you're using a tuple of vectors?  It's much simpler with arrays, as Ben has already shown with `vec`. But you can also use comprehensions pretty simply in either case:

```
julia> a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]);
julia> [i for i in hcat(a...)]
9-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 ⋮
```

The expression `hcat(a...)` "splats" your tuple and concatenates it into an array.  But remember that, unlike Python, Julia uses column-major array semantics. You have three column vectors in your tuple; is that what you intend?  (If they were row vectors — delimited by spaces — you could just use `[a...]` to do the concatenation).  Arrays are iterated through all elements, regardless of their dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation for comment so posting a modification @ben-hammer. Thanks for the example of flatten(), it was helpful to me.

But it did break if the tuples/arrays contained strings. Since `strings` are iterables the function would further break them down to characters. I had to insert condition to check for `ASCIIString` to fix that. The code is below

```
    function flatten(x, y)
        state = start(x)
        if state==false
            push!(y, x)
        else
            if typeof(x) <: String
                push!(y, x)
            else 
                while (!done(x, state)) 
                    (item, state) = next(x, state) 
                    flatten(item, y)
                end
            end
        end
        y
    end
    flatten(x)=flatten(x,Array(Any, 0))
```