# Array or set of conditional evaluation with julia

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, julia

I am new with Julia. I was wandering if it is possible to write in a single line an `if` statement in an array or a set in Julia.

For example in python I can write a list such as

```
s = [1 if np.random.uniform() < 0.5 else 0 for i in range(10)]
```

which in Julia, if I'm right, should be an array like this

```
s = []
for i in 0:10
  if rand()<0.5
    push!(s, 1)
  else
    push!(s, 0)
  end
end
```

I know I can write the `for` cycle in a single line i.e.

```
s =[1 for i in 1:10]
```

But what about the `if..else` statement?

Comment: `map(x -> rand(1)[]<0.5 ? 1 : 0, 1:10)` is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I think that will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @Guido suggested, you can use list comprehension just like python, more specifically:

```
s = [if rand() < 0.5 1 else 0 end for i in 1:10]
```

note that julia's if-else statement needs an `end`. i think this is the same as using `map`:

```
map(x -> rand() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0, 1:10)
```

Comment: What if the else condition should return a void index? for exemple if 8 on 10 of the elements are 1 then I will have an array of 8 elements insate of an array of  10 elements of which 2 are zeros. Thanks

Comment: @mictiz do you still want to do this with a single line list comprehension?

Comment: I would prefer so, otherwise I think I can do it like this
s = []
        for i in 1:N
          if  rand()[]<.5
            push!(s, i)
            end
        end
I guess

Comment: @mictiz in fact, you can do it more concisely with just another line `s=s[find(s)]`. i prefer to write two lines using above mentioned `map` syntax, because that's easy for reading.

Answer (score 2):

To specifically do,

```
s = [1 if np.random.uniform() < 0.5 else 0 for i in range(10)]
```

In Julia you can write,

```
 s = [rand()<0.5?1:0 for i=1:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a list comprehension. In Julia, this can be done using:

`> [(x,y) for x=1:2, y=3:4]
2x2 Array{(Int64,Int64),2}:
 (1,3)  (1,4)
 (2,3)  (2,4)`

See [Nested list comprehensions in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129125/nested-list-comprehensions-in-julia) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic, or faster in Julia:

```
convert(Vector{Int},rand(Bool,10))
```

or

```
1*rand(Bool,10)
```

or

```
1*(rand(10).<0.5)
```

or

```
ifelse(rand(Bool,10),0,1)   // ifelse is a function and avoid CPU branching
```

My intuition is that the first and last versions are fastest.